# Why my random function always not undeclared?

Tags: c++, class

I'm writing my code on linux . But g++ always tells me"Use of undeclared identifier 'random'".I don't know why I have declare it in "Myvector.h"

my code is like :

Myvector.h

```
class MyVector {
private:
  std::vector<double> data;
  const int N;
  static bool _bDim;
public:
  MyVector();      //默认初始化
  MyVector(int a); //设置维度初始化
  MyVector(std::initializer_list<double> list);
  ~MyVector();
  double &operator[](int);
  MyVector &operator=(const MyVector a) {
    MyVector b(outN(a));
    this->data = a.data;
    return *this;
  }; 
 friend MyVector random(int a);
}
#endif // MYVECTOR_H_
```

Myvector.cpp

```
#include "Myvector.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

bool MyVector::_bDim = true;

MyVector::MyVector() : N(3) {
  data = vector<double>(N, 0.0);
  _bDim = false;
};

MyVector::MyVector(int a) : N(a) {
  data = vector<double>(N, 0.0);
  _bDim = false;
};

MyVector::MyVector(std::initializer_list<double> list) : N(list.size()) {
  for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++) {
    data.push_back(*i);
  }
};
MyVector::~MyVector(){

};

double &MyVector::operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }
MyVector random(int a){
  MyVector u(a);
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    u[i]=rand();
  }
  return u;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Myvector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<math.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
MyVector z=random(1);
return 0;}
```

In fact ,I just know nothing about it. Is there someone going to help me?Thank you.
[image]
Below is nothing meaningful. I just need more words to ask this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `main` function of the `main.cpp` file the following function is called:

```
MyVector z=random(1);
```

This appears to be a function which takes a single `int` argument. Additionally, there is such a function defined in the `Myvector.cpp` but not declared in `Myvector.h` (i.e., the `main.cpp` file does not see any function declaration for the definition).

Update the `Myvector.h` header to declare the `MyVector random(int a)` function. Also, the `friend` declaration is for a `random` function with 2 parameters, which doesn't look right.

Comment: @saltkun There are many issues with the code you posted that all need to be addressed in addition to fixing the undefined symbol. I didn't try to fix it for correctness but the above definitely solves the problem, see [example](https://www.onlinegdb.com/).

Comment: In fact,my code is only have one parameter. it's old version with two ...I'm sorry.But computer show me the picture above.

Comment: @saltkun Your updated example has a `friend` with 1 argument but that **is not** a function declaration for the `random` function. See the working example in the link of my comment above.

Comment: @saltkun Here is the correct link to the [working example](https://onlinegdb.com/BJdTQ6OkU)

Comment: I know.Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the function `random` somewhere, e.g.

```
#include "Myvector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<math.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

MyVector random(int);

int main(){
    MyVector z=random(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E.g. stands for exempli gratia and means "for example". You have to provide a declaration and one possible way is to declare in main.cpp. Another possible way is to declare in MyVector.h. You can't declare in MyVector.cpp because you use the function in main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `random` in your `main` function. That one is not declared.
Declaring a `friend` function means that function has access to the class as if it were a method. It doesn't declare the function at any time, just allows it inside the class.

Comment: @saltkun This information is correct and if you're having a problem still then you still haven't properly declared the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `random` function is defined is some header file you have included. In your error message you see the return type of `random` is `long int`. And you have declared it as `MyVector`. I am not sure if math.h or time.h have it.

Solution 1: Change the name of your function.
Solution 2: Put your function in a namespace in order to avoid name ambiguity.